# Wrong expansion of variable in Makefile.am

Tags: makefile, automake, variable-expansion, brace-expansion

I am stuck with a strange variable expansion. Let me explain.

I have a project that uses automake, composed by `configure.ac`, `Makefile.am`.
Basically, in `Makefile.am` I'm doing:

```
ARCH = $(shell ${CURDIR}/./arch.sh)
...
noinst_HEADERS = license/${ARCH}/lchecker.h
proj_SOURCES = main.c license/${ARCH}/lchecker.c
proj_LDFLAGS = -avoid-version -Llicense/${ARCH}
```

./arch is doing just `uname -m` to determine the architecture needed, because I have to enter the correct directory.

When I run the build, I have this error:

```
Makefile:622: license/x86_64/.deps/lchecker.Po: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'license/x86_64/.deps/lchecker.Po'.  Stop.
```

and if I enter the `license` directory, I notice a new dir created called `${ARCH}/` where I find the missing `.deps` from `license/x86_64`.

I'm pretty sure it is an incorrect expansion problem; I've tried many ways but I failed.

Can anyone explain to me the right way to do this? Reading around the net I see that `Makefile.am` has a different syntax from `Makefile`.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to add some changes to see if the variable is corretly defined:

`AC_DEFINE([ARCH], ["$ARCH"], [arch check])`

`echo ARCH = "$ARCH"` printf `x86_64`
so the variable in defined in configure.ac, but the expansion is not correct again in Makefile.am.

Comment: @Mike Did u delete your answer ?

Comment: Yep. If it doesn't work I reckon you need a [mcve]. I can undelete it if it helps.

Comment: Well, actually I modified my code and used yours because was better than mine, of course. Anyway,I'll follow your advice and hope I can solve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `configure.ac`, use the macro [`AC_SUBST(varname,[value])`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html)
to create a make-variable `varname` in each the generated makefiles that will
have the value to which `value` was evaluated at the time when the makefile was generated.
`value` may be a shell-expansion. So e.g.

```
AC_SUBST(ARCH,[`./arch.sh`])
```

in `configure.ac` will create in each makefile the assignment:

```
ARCH = x86_64
```

assuming that `x86_64` is the standard output of `./arch.sh` at `./configure`-time
in the build directory. You may then assume that this variable is so assigned
in your `Makefile.am` and write the like of:

```
noinst_HEADERS = license/${ARCH}/lchecker.h
```

Comment: I did exactly what u suggest, but I have the same result :(

Comment: @Kyrol Did you regenerate the build system after that? - `make distclean; autoreconf; ./configure; make`.

Comment: Yes. I have a script `./build.sh` that does this: `autoreconf --force --install` `automake --add-missing` `autoconf`. Even if I put `make distclean` the result is the same.

Comment: @Kyrol  In that case I think the real problem isn't visible in your post. Better provide a [mcve].

Comment: `autoreconf` already calls `automake` and `autoconf` (that is the purpose of `autoreconf`), so your `build.sh` needs only call `autoreconf`.